# How to incorporate a linearlaout xml file in a compose file?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to use [Robinhood Spark](https://github.com/robinhood/spark) in my app but my entire UI is built using jetpack compose. I'm going through these [docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/resources) but it's only mentioned how you can use XML resource files like String, Dimensions, Colors, Images, Vector drawbles, Icons, and Fonts. I don't know which one Spark falls under. Looking at the XML code it's a LinearLayout but I can't see how that falls under any of the resource types I've mentioned prior. So for now I'm going through non-compose documentations to see if there is some kind of class or method I can use but would appreciate some feedback and help.

Comment: Did you also read the docs on [Android Views in Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop/interop-apis#views-in-compose)?

Answer (score 2):

It is as nglauber mentioned, but you would need to define layout parameters that will fit into your compose view as well.
More about it https://foso.github.io/Jetpack-Compose-Playground/viewinterop/androidview/

```
        AndroidView(factory = { ctx ->
            val view = LayoutInflater.from(ctx)
                .inflate(R.layout.activity_sample, null, false)
                .apply {
                    layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT)
                }
            // Use your view as usual...
            view
        }, update = {
           // here update your view or get element from it and update 
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AndroidView` to load your XML file.

```
AndroidView(
    factory = { context: Context ->
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(context)
           .inflate(R.layout.your_layout, null, false)
        // Use your view as usual... 
        view // return the view
    },
    update = { view ->
        // Update view if needed
    }
)
```